# Creating a dynamic case statement for changing number of values from source

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where i need to convert values in a Row  in source table to display as column_names and create those columns in the target.I have this below sample query doing that( 1/2 way). My issue is I may have 2CODES or 3CODES or 5CODES or more values in the source rows and my target table structure(no of columns) should be created like wise.

Please help me with any solutions for dynamically creating the no of columns based on values in the source. I have tried the below case stmt and was trying to see of we can use max/min function on row_number to resolve this issue( just a blind thought)

Please advice.

eg:

Source table SSS

```
NAME   ID   CODE
AAA     1    XXX
BBB     2    YYY
CCC     3    PPP
AAA     1    YYY
AAA     1    PPP
```

TARGET:TGT

```
NAME ID  XXX  YYY   PPP  
AAA   1   A    A     A
CCC   3   N    N     A
BBB   2   N    A     N
```

Converting multiple values from single row  into multiple columns for a given ID

This is what I tried:

```
insert into fat
select id,
       max(case when rownum = 1 then val else '' end),
       max(case when rownum = 2 then val else '' end),
       max(case when rownum = 3 then val else '' end),
       max(case when rownum = 4 then val else '' end)
from long_ordered
group by id


select * from fat



select id, va11 as  val from fat
union all select id, va12 from fat
union all select id, va13 from fat
union all select id, va14 from fat
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you need to use dynamic SQL and a cursor. See fully worked out example below.

Note that I am using dynamic SQL to create TGT table based on what's in SSS table. I then iterate through SSS table using a cursor, and update TGT table for each record in SSS. Updates are only done for 'A' entries, everything else is set to 'N' using a default.

```
create table SSS(Name varchar(3), ID int, Code varchar(3))
insert into SSS values
('AAA'  ,   1  ,  'XXX'),
('BBB'  ,   2  ,  'YYY'),
('CCC'  ,   3  ,  'PPP'),
('AAA'  ,   1  ,  'YYY'),
('AAA'  ,   1  ,  'PPP');


--get a list of columns based on code field
declare @columns nvarchar(max) = (select distinct N'[' + code + N'] char(1) null default ''N'',' from sss for xml path(''));
--remove trailing comma
set @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@Columns) - 1);

--declare dynamic sql command variable
declare @cmd nvarchar(max);
--populate command with SQL to create a table
set @cmd = N'CREATE TABLE TGT(Name varchar(3) not null, ID int not null, ' + @columns + ');';
--show command (for troubleshooting only)
select @cmd;

--execute command to create a new table.
exec sp_executesql @cmd;
go

--prepare the table by inserting the names and ids
insert into tgt(name, id)
select distinct name, id
from sss;
go

--declare variables
declare @name varchar(3), @id int, @code varchar(3);
declare @cmd nvarchar(max);

--declare cursor to iterate through sss
declare cur cursor fast_forward for 
select name, id, code
from sss;

open cur;

fetch next from cur into @name, @id, @code;

--main loop
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    set @cmd = 'UPDATE tgt SET ' + @code + ' = ''A'' WHERE [name] = ''' + @name + ''' and [id] = ' + cast(@id as varchar(5)) + ';';
    exec sp_executesql @cmd;
    fetch next from cur into @name, @id, @code;
END


close cur;
deallocate cur;
go

select * from tgt;
```